# SQL Subquery containing Joins

Tags: sql, join, hive

I'm using Hive hql. I am trying to inner join two tables filtering on `issue_type='Impediments'`

Now I have a new requirement to join `dm_jira__label` to include the `label` and `issue_id` columns. I have tried having a subquery adding the `issue_id` and `label` by using a left join with `dm_jira__label` on `issue_id`

```
  INNER JOIN datamart_core.dm_jira__release
  ON dm_jira.issue_id =  dm_jira__release.issue_id;
    (   
        SELECT b.issue_id, b.label AS jira_label
        FROM datamart_core.dm_jira__label as B, datamart_core.dm_jira__release AS K
        LEFT JOIN b
        ON b.issue_id=k.issue_id
    );
  WHERE dm_jira.issue_type = 'Impediment') AS J
```

I am getting the following error:

`AnalysisException: Illegal table reference to non-collection type: 'b' Path resolved to type: STRUCT<issue_id:DOUBLE,label:STRING>`

See the full code below. thanks in advance.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
j.project_key AS jira_project_key,
j.issue_type,
j.issue_assignee AS impediment_owner,
j.issue_status AS impediment_status,
j.issue_priority AS impediment_priority,
j.issue_summary AS impediment_summary,
j.`release` AS jira_release,
j.sow AS sow_num,
j.issue_due_date_utc AS jira_issue_due_date_utc,
j.issue_id AS jira_issue_id,
s.sow_family


from (
--Subquery to combine dm_jira and dm_jira__release
  SELECT dm_jira.project_key,
  dm_jira.issue_type,
  dm_jira.issue_assignee,
  dm_jira.issue_status,
  dm_jira.issue_priority,
  dm_jira.issue_summary,
  dm_jira.issue_due_date_utc,
  dm_jira.issue_id,
  dm_jira__release.`release`,
  dm_jira__release.sow

  from datamart_core.dm_jira


  INNER JOIN datamart_core.dm_jira__release
  ON dm_jira.issue_id =  dm_jira__release.issue_id;
    (   
        SELECT b.issue_id, b.label AS jira_label
        FROM datamart_core.dm_jira__label as B, datamart_core.dm_jira__release AS K
        LEFT JOIN b
        ON b.issue_id=k.issue_id
    );
  WHERE dm_jira.issue_type = 'Impediment') AS J


INNER JOIN datamart_core.dm_asoe_jira_scrum_summary AS S
ON j.`release` = s.jira_release
AND j.sow = s.sow_num
AND j.project_key = s.jira_project_key;
```

Comment: You're using B and b to refer to different tables : it might work but it could avoid trouble not to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`;` ends a whole statement, don't use it at the end of sub-queries or joins.

Using meaningless aliases such as `B` or `K` or `J` harms readability, don't do it.

`FROM x, y` is the same as `FROM x CROSS JOIN y`, it's not a list of tables you're going to join.  This means that you have the following code...

```
(   
  SELECT
     b.issue_id, b.label AS jira_label
  FROM
     datamart_core.dm_jira__label as B
  CROSS JOIN
     datamart_core.dm_jira__release AS K
  LEFT JOIN
     b
       ON b.issue_id=k.issue_id
)
```

- The `b` in the `LEFT JOIN` isn't a table, and causes your syntax error.

Then, your sub query just sits in the middle of the code, it's not joined on or used in any way.  I **think** you intended a pattern more like this...

```
FROM
  datamart_core.dm_jira
INNER JOIN
  datamart_core.dm_jira__release
    ON dm_jira.issue_id =  dm_jira__release.issue_id;
LEFT JOIN
(   
  <your sub-query>
)
  AS fubar
    ON fubar.something = something.else
WHERE
  dm_jira.issue_type = 'Impediment'
```

Even then, you don't actually need nested sub-queries at all.   You can just keep adding joins, such as this...

```
SELECT
  jira.project_key          AS jira_project_key,
  jira.issue_type,
  jira.issue_assignee       AS impediment_owner,
  jira.issue_status         AS impediment_status,
  jira.issue_priority       AS impediment_priority,
  jira.issue_summary        AS impediment_summary,
  jrel.`release`            AS jira_release,
  jrel.sow                  AS sow_num,
  jira.issue_due_date_utc   AS jira_issue_due_date_utc,
  jira.issue_id             AS jira_issue_id,
  jlab.label,
  summ.sow_family
FROM
  datamart_core.dm_jira                      AS jira
INNER JOIN
  datamart_core.dm_jira__release             AS jrel
    ON  jrel.issue_id = jira.issue_id
LEFT JOIN
  datamart_core.dm_jira__label               AS jlab
    ON  jlab.issue_id = jrel.issue_id
INNER JOIN
  datamart_core.dm_asoe_jira_scrum_summary   AS summ
    ON  summ.jira_release     = jrel.`release`
    AND summ.sow_num          = jrel.sow
    AND summ.jira_project_key = jira.project_key
WHERE
  jira.issue_type = 'Impediment'
;
```

Comment: @ITPersonHelpMe & MatBailie Comma has lower precedence than keyword joins, so the 1st query translation with cross join is wrong, the left join is done first in the comma code, one could parenthesize to correct the translation. (There are still the same naming problems.) (An alias doesn't denote a table, it is a placeholder for a row.)